# Horizontal scrolling of div as page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I try to make a horizontal scrolling inside a `div`. Scrolling happens as the user scrolls the page. Somehow I manage to scroll the `div`, but it does not look pleasant. I don't know what the error is happening.

Let me try to explain to you the UI as much as I can. I have a `div` somewhere in the middle of the page. When the user scroll and reach the scrolling section, it start scrolling from right to left as user scroll, once the next section appears in the viewport, its horizontal scrolling gets to stop. The same thing happens when the user moves from bottom to top inside the page. here is my code sample.

Please help. let me know in the comment if you want any additional information about the problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var activityContainer = $(".activities-container").offset().top;
  var activityHeight = $(".activity-container").css("height");
  var activityTotalWidth = parseFloat($(".activities-section").css("width"));
  var nextSection = $(".footer-container").offset().top;
  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    let top = $(this).scrollTop();
    let scrollOffset = top - activityContainer;
    if (top >= activityContainer && top < nextSection) {
      $(".activities-container").addClass("scroll-activity");
      scrollActivity(scrollOffset);

    } else {
      $(".activities-container").removeClass("scroll-activity");
    }


  });

  function scrollActivity(value) {
    value = -value;
    console.log(value);
    $(".activities-section").css("transform", "translateX(" + value + "px" + ")");
  }
})
```

```css
.full-height {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.all-center {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bg-gray {
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

.bg-black {
  background-color: #333;
}

.activities-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.activities-container>.col-md-12 {
  width: 180%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.activity-box {
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  width: 30%;
}

.activity-box:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 60px;
}

.flex-direction-column {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.horizontal-center {
  justify-content: center;
}

.color-white {
  color: #fff;
}

.scroll-activity {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
}

.scroll-activity+.row {
  margin-top: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row full-height bg-black">
  </div>
  <div class="row full-height bg-gray">
  </div>

  <div class="row bg-black activities-container pdr-default pdl-default full-height horizontal-center flex-direction-column">
    <h3 class="large-heading color-white opensans-bold mgb-60">Our Activities</h3>
    <div class="col-md-12 activities-section ">
      <div class="activity-box">
        <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" class="img" alt="Image" />
        <h3 class="opensans color-white heading mgt-10">Heading</h3>
        <p class="paragraph color-white opensans mgt-10">Lorep ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorep ipsum is simply dummy text.

        </p>

      </div>
      <div class="activity-box">
        <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/arctichare.png" class="img" alt="Image" />
        <h3 class="opensans color-white heading mgt-10">Heading</h3>
        <p class="paragraph color-white opensans mgt-10">Lorep ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorep ipsum is simply dummy text.

        </p>

      </div>
      <div class="activity-box">
        <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/boat.png" class="img" alt="Image" />
        <h3 class="opensans color-white heading mgt-10 ">Heading</h3>
        <p class="paragraph color-white opensans mgt-10">Lorep ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorep ipsum is simply dummy text.

        </p>

      </div>
      <div class="activity-box">
        <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/arctichare.png" class="img" alt="Image" />
        <h3 class="opensans color-white heading mgt-10">Heading</h3>
        <p class="paragraph color-white opensans mgt-10">Lorep ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorep ipsum is simply dummy text.

        </p>

      </div>
      <div class="activity-box">
        <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" class="img" alt="Image" />
        <h3 class="opensans color-white heading mgt-10">Heading</h3>
        <p class="paragraph color-white opensans mgt-10">Lorep ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorep ipsum is simply dummy text.

        </p>

      </div>
      <div class="activity-box">
        <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/boat.png" class="img" alt="Image" />
        <h3 class="opensans color-white heading">Heading</h3>
        <p class="paragraph color-white opensans">Lorep ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorep ipsum is simply dummy text.

        </p>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
  <div class=" row footer-container full-height bg-gray">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: codepen link for the same is https://codepen.io/pranaysharma995/full/yLNORdw

Comment: This is handled very well by scrollmagic, see my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60161393/how-to-horizontally-move-a-div-as-you-scroll-down-in-javascript-and-or-css/60167337#60167337

Comment: @Doughballs thanks. I will try but do you any insight on how we can make this either with vanilla javascript or jquery.

Comment: You can, but it would take me a long time to debug your code - I saw at least two issues (1 was the jump, and 2 was on resize), and there may be more. Kudos for even trying though - and I'm not discouraging you, this kind of mentality is very positive. But handling the pinning and unpinning properly, and resizes, it's pretty complex which is why I personally would lean on a library that has it covered. I think solving number 1 would mean setting the new scrolltop position to be the top of that container, if you're not already doing so.